# Cloudformation AWS: choose between Security Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I'm designing a cloudformation template, but I need to choose between several security groups

I have defined a parameter and two conditions to enable one policy or another that has the same name (to maintain dependencies)

But the template does not work for both options,

When the parameter has the True option the stack works,and with the value False shows the following error:

```
Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [mySecurityGroup] in the Resources block of the template
```

this is the fragment of the template:

```
 Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: EC2 KeyPair 
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
  Reception:
    Description: Enable reception
    Default: False
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: 
      - True
      - False
Conditions:
  Enable:
    !Equals [True, !Ref Reception]
  Disable:
    !Equals [False, !Ref Reception]
Resources:
  myVPC:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: 'true'
      EnableDnsHostnames: 'true'
      InstanceTenancy: default
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: myVPC
  mySubNet:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: mySubNet
  mySecurityGroup:
    Condition: Disable
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2 
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: udp
          FromPort: 4114
          ToPort: 4114
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: mySecurityGroup
  mySecurityGroup:
    Condition: Enable
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: udp
          FromPort: 5683
          ToPort: 5683
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: mySecurityGroup
  myEC2:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      ImageId: ami-028188d9b49b32a80
      InstanceType: t2.nano
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - SubnetId: !Ref mySubNet
          AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'
          DeviceIndex: 0
          GroupSet:
            - !Ref mySecurityGroup
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: myEC2
```

I'm not sure which is the right way

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work, please explain the error or result.

Comment: When the parameter has the True option the stack works,and with the value False shows the following error:

```
Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [mySecurityGroup] in the Resources block of the template
```

Comment: You don't need to create two entirely different security groups, you could use the same security group - but add ingress rules conditionally (Resource type is AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress). You can then use the Fn::IF function to determine whether to add the ingress rule or not.  See Fn::If on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html. I think you're going to run into issues with your method, because cloudformation will first try create the new resource before deleting the redundant one - creating conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well hell, I can't leave a comment since my Rep is 48, not 50. :(

Anyway, I don't have an actual ANSWER to your question, but I hope what I have here will help you along.

1. In your Parameters Section, you have the following:

```
Conditions:
  Enable:
    !Equals [True, !Ref Reception]
  Disable:
    !Equals [False, !Ref Reception]
```

1a. This isn't going to work. You just need one conditional statement:

```
Conditions: # Checks to see if Conditional Values are True
  ReceptionYes: !Equals [ !Ref Reception, True]
```

2. This is where it gets sticky.

You need a conditional line in Resources like (Where I am stuck, is where to put this line below):

```
          !If [ReceptionYes, !Ref mySecurityGroup2, !Ref mySecurityGroup1]
```

First !Ref if True, else, use second !Ref

Now, in **THEORY**, you **SHOULD** be able to do the following:

```
  mySecurityGroup1:
    Condition: Disable
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2 
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: udp
          FromPort: 4114
          ToPort: 4114
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: mySecurityGroup
  mySecurityGroup2:
    Condition: Enable
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: udp
          FromPort: 5683
          ToPort: 5683
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: mySecurityGroup
```

Well, if this doesn't work, I hope it gets you a bit closer to an answer. :D